# How to read the number of battery charges?

Tags: java, android, power-management

as mentioned above, I want to get the total number of battery chrarges.
The batery Intent I'm already using only shows me Level, Voltage, Temperature ... but not the total loading cycles.

Comment: Are you sure this is being tracked?  What counts as a battery charge?  If it goes for 20% to 30%?  Or up to 99%?

Comment: Excellent question. Unfortunately (I don't know definitively), I think the answer is going to be that this isn't tracked or accessible.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I thougt I've seen it in the testinfo but I was wrong. so I'm gonna track it myself.

Comment: Note:  On Android.SE, there's a [related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78209/is-there-a-battery-cycle-counter-app), in which the users discuss ready-made third-party apps which can keep track of charge cycle count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an Intent receiver to receive the broadcast for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.

Broadcast Action: This is a sticky broadcast containing the charging state, level, and other information about the battery. See [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) for documentation on the contents of the Intent.

You can *not* receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()`. See `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`, `ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY`, `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`, and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` for distinct battery-related broadcasts that are sent and can be received through manifest receivers.

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.
Constant Value: "`android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED`"